# Error with FROM clause containing a subquery

Tags: sql-server

I was running this query in MSSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ABC)
```

It gives an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

This same command runs just fine on a DB2 database. I know this query doesn't make any sense I was just testing functionality.

So, are there certain features, eg., `SELECT in FROM` clause, that are not supported in MSSQL that are supported in DB2?

Comment: Try putting an alias on the subquery: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ABC) AS t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to give the subquery an alias like so:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ABC) subTable
```

Which translates to:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ABC) as subTable
```

The `AS` is optional.

Comment: Whilst the `As` *is* optional, missing it out is lazy and can cause lots of confusion! "If you don't alias it, it don't get in production"